# Não está aparecendo a pasta node modules no VS Code

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Bom, há cerca de três dias eu estou tentando incluir o node module no meu arquivo, mas ele não está aparecendo mesmo depois de fazer `npm init` depois `npm install -g`.

[Imagem de como está a pasta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crrGV.png)

Além disso, graças a falta da pasta, eu não consigo usar o JSON-SERVER e saber com o meu host para continuar os estudos.

Reforço que eu uso o Visual Studio Code e uso MACOS para a programação.

Comment: Não tenho certeza mas ao fazer `npm install -g` você instalou os módulos node como globais. Acho que deveria ter feito apenas `npm install` dentro do diretório do projeto.

Comment: Quando se faz em npm install só aparece o package-json-lock.

Comment: Resolvido o problema... Por eu usar o MACOS, o certo é `npx json-server --watch db.json` Obrigado a quem se disponibilizou.

Answer (score -2):

vai no menu do VSCode e navegue até File:Exclude

verifique se existe a opção **/node_modules no bloco File:Exclude. Se existir remova-o.

Caminho:

CTRL+, -> Pesquise Exclude -> Deve ser o primeiro bloco retornado

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu tirei essa pasta, mas mesmo assim não aparece.

Comment: Voc^ esta abrindo o vscode na mesma pasta que tem o arquivo package.json ? tem como anexar um print?